# I broke my Laravel framework with migration renaming

Tags: php, laravel

I had a good working Laravel structure with database migrations and seeding.
But I wanted my migration file,classes,db table be renamed to **CreateOrganizationsTable** instead of **CreateOrganisationsTable**

So I changed the migration filename, all classes and routes.

But when I execute `php artisan migrate:reset` in my Homestead box, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'CreateOrganisationsTable' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php on line 299
```

Artisan created some link I'm unable to fix at the moment.

Comment: Can you rename it back to make it work?

Comment: have you done a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: yes I did composer dump-autoload on the Homestead box. ->Generating autoload files. but same error

Comment: if I rename my class in my migration file back to class CreateOrganisationsTable extends Migration { it works back again. But how can I rename migration classes the right way?

Comment: I got it back to work again by executing composer dump-autoload immediately after renaming the migration class.

If you execute any php artisan migrate command before the composer command, the composer dump-autoload doesn't have any effect.

So the command order is crucial. Thanks Mark

Comment: Have you also tried running: php artisan dump-autoload?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` after renaming the file and the column in the `migrations` table worked for me!

Answer (score 35):

As Morale mentioned you must reset or rollback to a point before your new migration or make the changes manually. I knew this but was still getting the problem after changing only the timestamps to have the migrations run in a different order.

You must run `composer dump-autoload` even if you didn't change the class name.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Don't forget to also rename the class inside the file

Comment: Just to elaborate on this, `class CreateResourceTagsTable extends Migration` would need to become `class CreateTagsTable extends Migration` if I were to rename my migration to `create_tags_table`.

Answer (score 6):

I have had similar problems with the php artisan:rollback, and I just opened my laravel project and went to the next directory:

> **vendor\composer\autoload_static.php**

and modified the name of the php migration that was changed, hope this help's you :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you run the `migrate:reset` command, artisan wants to call the down method on all classes. And since you renamed the class, he can't find it anymore!

So before renaming your class and/or file, run `php artisan migrate:reset` which will clean your database and remove all tables, and right after that simply run `php artisan migrate`. You should have a working database again.

If the `migrate:reset` command still doesn't work, you can simply delete the tables manually (don't forget to remove the migration table aswell) and run `php artisan migrate` again.

**Edit:** In case you don't actually want to run the `migrate:reset`, but just rename the migration, you can edit the name of the file (and class) . But after that you have to manually edit the table `migrations` in your database. Find the corresponding row, and edit the name of the file to match the new name.

Answer (score 5):

1. rename your file
2. rename the class
3. rename the 'migration' column in 'migrations' table in database.

Answer (score 3):

In laravel renaming migration works fine if you do it the right way.

i have also renamed my migration files many times, and it works as expected,

but if you want to **rename the migration** then you have to **take care of two things**:

1. ***first rename the filename***
2. ***open that migration file and rename the Class name also***

Renaming the file :
change your filename from `2019_06_28_131130_create_organisations_table` to `2019_06_28_131130_create_organizations_table` or whatever name you want.

**Open that migration file and Rename the class name in that file** as per your new name:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

//change it from
//class CreateOrganisationsTable extends Migration {
//to
class CreateOrganizationsTable extends Migration {
```

i think you have renamed the migration file but you have forgotten to rename the Class name so do that and try to run `php artisan migrate:refresh` it will work as you want.

Answer (score 2):

I've performed a composer dump-autoload and everything works fine now

Answer (score 1):

If you're using composer, then I think you forgot to dump-autoload

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the above fail, as they did for me try setting directly the name of the table

```
class NameModel extends Model {
    public $table = 'name_exact_of_the_table';
```

Answer via [How to fix error Base table or view not found: 1146 Table laravel relationship table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770785/how-to-fix-error-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-relationship-t)  credit https://stackoverflow.com/users/1607975/jpasosa

Answer (score 0):

The solutions proposed above did not suit me because they involved dropping tables, which is not desirable in production.

Here is my solution :

Laravel has created a table which records the name of migration files that have already been run, which can be displayed with :

```
$migrations = DB::table('migrations')->get();
dd($migrations);
```

From there you can modify the name recorded by your application of your migration file :

```
DB::table('migrations')->where('migration', $old_file_name)
    ->update([
        'migration' => $new_file_name,
    ]);
```