# How to fix error Base table or view not found: 1146 Table laravel relationship table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am a new of laravel I try to create relationship many to many between table,My problem when I am insert data in to database I got errors

QueryException in Connection.php line 713: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'learn.category_posts' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `category_posts` (`category_id`, `posts_id`) values (4, ))

can anyone help me pls . and here below is my migrate and code:

2016_08_04_131009_create_table_posts.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

2016_08_04_131053_create_table_categories.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

2016_08_04_131413_create_table_category_posts.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and my model Posts.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posts extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories'; 

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Posts');
    }   
}
```

My PostsController.php

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('create',compact('categories'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
   $post = new Posts;
   $post->title = $request->title;
   $post->body = $request->body;
   $post->categories()->attach($request->categories_id);

    return redirect()->route('posts.index');
}
```

My View create.blade.php

```
{!!Form::open(array('route' => 'store', 'method' => 'POST'))!!}

    {{Form::text('title')}}<br>
    {{Form::textarea('body')}}<br>
    <select name="categories_id" multiple>
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <br>
    {{Form::submit('submit')}}

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: Did you create a `learn` table? mysql is looking for it and can't find it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems Laravel is trying to use `category_posts` table (because of many-to-many relationship). But you don't have this table, because you've created `category_post` table. Change name of the table to `category_posts`.

Comment: QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `category_posts` (`category_id`, `posts_id`) values (2, ))

Comment: Again, you have `post_id` column, but Laravel looks for 'posts_id', because your model is `Posts`, not `Post`. You could rename you model to `Post`, and then set table name back to the `category_post` and keep `post_id` in you pivot table.

Comment: QueryException in Connection.php line 713: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'posts_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `category_posts` (`category_id`, `posts_id`) values (2, ))

Comment: I guess you're getting integrity violation, because you didn't save `posts` model before `attach()` in `PostsController@store`. Try to use `$post->save();` just before using `attach()` method.

Answer (score 37):

Laravel tries to guess the name of the table, you have to specify it directly so that it does not give you that error..

Try this:

```
class NameModel extends Model {
    public $table = 'name_exact_of_the_table';
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: When renaming the classes and files fails, migrate:reset fails as does composer dump-autoload then this did the trick for me

Answer (score 20):

`Schema::table` is to modify an existing table, use `Schema::create` to create new.

Answer (score 17):

The main problem for causing your table unable to migrate, is that you have running query on your **"AppServiceProvider.php"** try to check your `serviceprovider` and disable code for the meantime, and run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 9):

You can add this in **Post Model**,

```
public function categories()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category','category_post','post_id','category_id');                 
}
```

`category_post` indicate the table you want to use.
`post_id` indicate the column where you want to store the posts id.
`category_id` indicate the column where you want to store the categories id.

Comment: perfect . this is my case .

Answer (score 7):

For solving your Base Table or view not found error you can do As @Alexey Mezenin said that change table name `category_post` to `category_posts`,

but if you don't want to change the name like in my case i am **using `inventory` table so i don't want to suffix it by `s` so i will provide table name in model as `protected $table = 'Table_name_as_you_want'` and then there is no need to change table name**:

Change your Model of the module in which you are getting error for example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'inventory';

    protected $fillable = [
        'supply', 'order',
    ];
}
```

you have to provide table name in model then it will not give error.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is, change the default table name assigned for the model. Simply put following code,
`protected $table = 'category_posts';` instead of `protected $table = 'posts';` then it'll do the trick.

However, if you refer Laravel documentation you'll find the answer. Here what it says,

> By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class(model) will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified

Better to you use artisan command to make model and the migration file at the same time, use the following command,

`php artisan make:model Test --migration`

This will create a model class and a migration class in your Laravel project. Let's say it created following files,

**Test.php**

**2018_06_22_142912_create_tests_table.php**

If you look at the code in those two files you'll see,

**2018_06_22_142912_create_tests_table.php** files' up function,

```
 public function up()
 {
      Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->timestamps();
      });
 }
```

Here it automatically generated code with the table name of 'tests' which is the plural name of that class which is in **Test.php** file.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your model

```
protected $table = 'your table name';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change/add in your PostController: (and change PostsController to PostController)

```php
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('create',compact('categories'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Posts;
    $post->title = $request->get('title'); // CHANGE THIS
    $post->body = $request->get('body'); // CHANGE THIS
    $post->save(); // ADD THIS
    $post->categories()->attach($request->get('categories_id')); // CHANGE THIS

    return redirect()->route('posts.index'); // PS ON THIS ONE
}
```

PS: using route() means you have named your route as such

```php
Route::get('example', 'ExampleController@getExample')->name('getExample');
```

**UPDATE**

The comments above are also right, change your 'Posts' Model to 'Post'

Answer (score 0):

try checking in the app if you are using the tables before it's created
such as appServiceProvider.php

you might be calling the table without being created it, if you are, comment it then run php artisan migrate.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur due to wrong spell or undefined database name. Make sure your database name, table name and all column name is same as from phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing this error but your issue is different and you're tired of searching for a long time then this might help you.

If you have changed your database and updated .env file and still facing same issue then you should check C:\xampp\htdocs{your-project-name}\bootstrap\cache\config.php file and replace or remove the old database name and other changed items.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error "`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found`" and  you have no problem in your code, check if you have wrote the first letter of the table in capital letter.

Inspections >> inspections

capital case and small case letters matters on AWS environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the table name in a relationship, Laravel follows alphabetical order to generate the pivot table name for a many-to-many relationship.

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Model::class, 'table_name');
```