# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blogchan_laravel_blog.categories' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

[image]

[image]

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blogchan_laravel_blog.categories' doesn't exist
```

What is the solution to solve the problem? Help me please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error Base table or view not found: 1146 Table laravel relationship table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770785/how-to-fix-error-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-relationship-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Clear that You Have Not Created any Table Like **categories** In Your Database.
First Create a Migration File For categories Then run Migration or Create the table directly in your database then Check

Answer (score 0):

As the error show, the `categories` table does not exist in your database. In your sql query you are trying to join `categories` table.

I am not sure what you trying to do but please make sure you create a migration for `categories` table and define a `Category` model.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, categories table is missing from your database. First create a migration for the table if you haven't already and then run the migration. That should resolve the issue.